# The file is corrupted ckfinder Aspx

Tags: asp.net, ckfinder

now i use ckfinder 2.5.0.1 lastest version with ckeditor 4.5.1 lastest, too.
but when i upload an img to server by ckfinder with some config:

Config.ascx

```
public override bool CheckAuthentication()
{
    return true;
}
```

WebForm1.aspx.cs

> CKEditorControl1.Language = "en";
>               CKFinder.FileBrowser
>               _FileBrowser = new CKFinder.FileBrowser();
>               _FileBrowser.BasePath = "/ckfinder/";
>               _FileBrowser.SetupCKEditor(CKEditorControl1);

it happened:

1. with project Web empty: success
2. with project Web app: the file is corrupted

**They all have the same Url from root.**

https://www.upsieutoc.com/images/2015/07/04/1e9405.png

https://www.upsieutoc.com/images/2015/07/04/2bb953.png

Comment: please someone help :( i don't understand why :(